# qgis print composer: more then one "overviews" to show overlap of more then two maps

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a map composition with 3 pages (maps). I would like to draw the overlapping on every map. So the first map is overlapping the second, and the second is overlapped by the first an the third.

To show the overlap, you can use the overview-feature but there you can just choose ONE map - the first OR the third. I need do choos both. Is that possible? Or is there a other way to draw the overlap?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's currently possible to have more than one map referenced by the overview feature.

A slightly hackish solution would be to put two map items onto the second page. The left map item would reference the map on page 1 and the right map item would reference the map on page  3. It might require some manual fine-tuning to get all settings right but it should work.

Comment: According to your sollution I placed a copy of the second map over it. Its working so far but the "empty" map is now on top - I would like to group the initial map and the copy but I can choose just the map on the top.